# Getting Internal Server Error while performing Stress testing(Load testing) in Apache J-meter

Tags: jmeter, tibco, stress-testing, statistica

So we have three development servers(A,B,C).In "A" and "B" servers we have installed  Tibco Statistica of same version and with same configurations also we have installed Apache J-Meter in C Server .We have constructed a Model in the Statistica which takes input values from excel sheet and gives output. We want to perform Stress testing on these two servers (A,B) using Apache J-meter in "C" server, to find out how many requests the model(in Servers A and B) can take in a given time interval.
The server A is working good and we are not getting any errors in the given time interval but we are getting many failures in the Server B(More than 80%)
The Error in the Server B is "Internal Server Error" 20% of the requests are getting the response while the rest of the 80% is getting failed
For E.g:- If i pass 60 requests under 20 sec time interval 
1)For Server A all the 60 requests are getting response
2)For Server B only 18-20 requests are getting response and the rest are failing with "Internal Server Error"
After reading from some blogs about the error i have found that the communication interruption(between the servers) is the main cause of this issue,But in our case there is no interruption and the process monitor was able to capture the events during the time of testing

can anyone please help me out.?

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting a H[TTP Status code above 499 and below 600](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#5xx_Server_errors) it means that the error happened on the **server side** hence there is nothing to do with your JMeter test, most probably your "Server B" differs somehow from the "Server A".

In particular [HTTP Status Code 500 - Internal Server Error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/500) means that:

> the server encountered an unexpected condition that prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> This error response is a generic "catch-all" response. Usually, this indicates the server cannot find a better 5xx error code to response. Sometimes, server administrators log error responses like the 500 status code with more details about the request to prevent the error from happening again in the future.

First of all I would check application logs on the "Server B" as most probably you will be figure out the cause of the failure from there.

Second make sure that "Server B" has enough headroom to operate in terms of CPU, RAM, etc. as it might be the case of simple lack of computing power or something like this, you can do this using [JMeter PerfMon Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-monitor-your-server-health-performance-during-jmeter-load-test/)

Third would be looking for the exact error message at the [TIBCO Support](https://support.tibco.com/s/) page and reaching out to their support if you cannot figure out the cause yourself

Comment: Thank you Dmitri. i will check the three steps